# Using the Matrix protocol in React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to build a chat app on top of the matrix protocol using React Native but the official `matrix-js-sdk` requires the `http` protocol.

Are there any official (or community maintained) solution for integrating matrix in RN?

Comment: Matrix protocol os based on HTTP, isn't it?  I don't quite see what is the problem.

Comment: From my understanding, it is based on the nodejs http interface which is not available in react native https://nodejs.org/api/http.html